# MKMapSnapshotter 'completionHandler' not called on iPhone 6/6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, mapkit, mkmapsnapshotter

I'm developing app that works with `MKMapSnapshotter` API.
It makes snap shot of map with required region.
Code for it called from foreground app state and from main thread, like this:

```
MKMapSnapshotOptions* options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
options.region                = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locationCenter, span);
options.scale                 = UIScreen.mainScreen.scale;
options.size                  = size;

__block typeof(self) blockSelf = self;

MKMapSnapshotter* snapshooter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions: options];

[snapshooter startWithCompletionHandler: ^(MKMapSnapshot* snapshot, NSError* error) {
    blockSelf.snapshot = snapshot.image;
}];
```

I noticed that on iPhone 6 and 6+ completion handler is never being called, tested on iOS 8 and 9.
In the iOS simulator, everything works as expected, tested with Xcode 7, iOS 8 & 9.
Any ideas - how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
__block __strong typeof(self) blockSelf = self
```